# Distance from point to plane given point and plane

Tags: linear-algebra

In my Linear Algebra 2 class, I was assigned the following question taken from the section of the textbook regarding closest point problems and least squares etc.:

"Find the distance from the point $b = (1, 2,−1)$ to the plane $x − 2y + z = 3$.
Hint: Move the point and the plane so that the plane goes through the origin.''

I'm confused because it seems like it's a pretty easy question where I just take the projection of b onto the plane using the plane's normal vector $n = <1,-2,1>$. However, the hint is throwing me off and now I'm unsure of whether the method I described above is actually the way they want me to solve this question.

Anybody have any ideas as to how/why I would need to use this hint? I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: The formula for projection is valid for planes through the origin, i.e. linear  subspaces.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc ah I missed that important detail. Any idea how I shift the point and plane? I know if the plane passes through origin then (0,0,0) should satisfy the plane equation but I don't know how to shift the point and plane.

Comment: It's easy, you need to get rid of that $3$ so set $z'=z+3$ and leave $x$ and $y$ the same. Your point will become $(1,2,2)$.

Comment: @Vasili yes okay that's what I've just read elsewhere, thank you for your help. So the new plane equation is $x-2y+(z+3)=3$?

Comment: You have to shift them by the same vector in order to preserve the distance. The new plane will be $x'-2y'+z'=0.$ Now assuming that $x-2y+z=3,$ you should figure out a vector $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ so that $x'=x-x_0, y'-y_0,z'=z-z_0$ satisfy $x'-2y'+z'=0.$ Then you replace $(1,2,-1)$ by $(1-x_0,2-y_0,-1-z_0).$ There are many choices for $(x_0,y_0,z_0).$ For example any point in the original plane will do.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc So my new plane could be $x-2y+(z+3)=3$ then? Because taking the point (0,0,0) the equation is now satisfied i.e. $0-2(0)+(0+3)=3$. So the plane has now shifted three units down which means I should shift my point 3 units down as well? Do I have this correct?

Comment: That's correct, although I prefer to use new symbols: the equation of the new plane $x'-2y'+z'=0,$ where $x'=x,y'=y,z'=z-3.$ The new  point will be $(1,2,-1).$